# Unarmed Sorcerer's Spell Focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, spellcasting-focus

My sorcerer player has taken exception to the existence of the Hat of Wizardry being wearable on the head but not usable by a sorcerer, a class whom in their opinion shouldn't need any spell focuses or components in the first place.

So far the player has come up with the following but I don't think any are RAW legal:

1. Turning the Crystal Spellcasting Focus into a simple amulet using string.
2. Attaching Ruby of the War Mage to the palm of the hand/glove/gauntlet.
3. Replacing an eye with a Ruby of the War Mage (both about 1 inch diameter)

How many 5e RAW legal ways are there to allow a sorcerer to cast empty handed but as though they have a spell focus? (No component pouches)

(or was I wrong about any of the above three?)

Comment: Hey Blam! I think you have a good question here, but it is actually several good questions. On this site, we keep it it one question per post. My advice would be to split it up into several questions. One can ask about your #1. The second can ask about #2 and #3 together (I think they are close enough to do so). And the third can ask about legal ways to allow sorcerers to cast empty handed.

Comment: Related on [Can a glass eye be an arcane focus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116094/can-a-glass-eye-be-an-arcane-focus)

Comment: I think you can probably distill your question down to just "Is there a RAW way to avoid having to touch either a focus or component pouch during spellcasting?"